# Is there a way to filter one model based on another models created date?

Tags: sql-server, reactjs, django-rest-framework

EDIT: BLAH BLAH there's no code QQ. I'm aware this is a wall of text so before you come in and shrug it off or post unhelpful comments read through and you'll understand why there isn't any code here. If on the other hand you're going to ask me for a specific piece of my code that you feel might help you solve it that's a different matter.

This is more of a conceptual question than something I can actually show code for. If needed please ask me to and I will post what I can, but really you can just assume I have a standard working model, serializer, and view that I don't have any clue how to implement the functionality I'm asking about into. I have a Django application running the REST framework. I have two models. Lets call them Quotes and Lines. Picture the quote as a receipt. That receipt has lines that tell you what each item on it is alongside any other info about that item such as cost. Individually I can show both of these inside the API. The problem is, when I try to actually load the entire data set that my users need I am displaying data that while filtered to only show the past 2 years still presents 39,000 results. Now, imagine each quote has anywhere up to 50 lines and you can see where my problem begins. Because the quotes have dates I can filter, but the lines are related via a "QuoteID" I can't figure out how to filter lines down in my models/serializers such that I pull quotes by the last 2 years filter and afterwards I ONLY retrieve the lines that have a matching id to the quotes pulled. Essentially, in SQL this would be an inner join. I need to do so in Django REST framework so that my application doesn't shatter every time I remove the result cap. Sorry I know this is a long wall of text, but since my code isn't really going to be helpful here I wanted to be thorough. If there is any code you need to see to help sort through this conceptually please let me know and I'll post it.

I have given the models a relationship using models.foreignkey(). This does get them displaying properly in terms of the relationship IE lines 1-5 match quote ID 1, but this does not properly limit the line data to only the quotes that were pulled down with the date filter.

I do have a working relationship where if I limit the results to any abitrary smaller number, lets say 60, I get 60 quotes and 60 lines that have the proper matching ID's, but unfortunately this isn't entirely correct because 60 quotes may have 300 lines in theory since each quote can have many. So, when I uncap the search results I need it to give me 2 years worth of quotes filtered by dates, and only the lines pertaining to those 2 years worth filtered by matching ID.

I am hoping there is a way to essentially filter one model (the lines model) by another models previously received data. The less results I have to pull from lines the better. I thought about doing a simple query direct from the front end because it would allow me to pull specifically one quotes line data upon selection, but I'd prefer to keep all database connections on the backend if possible.

Comment: @JPG Shame you didn't read it or you'd know that I can't put code samples in for something I don't know how to code. It's a conceptual question clearly meant for somebody willing to read and help me come up with a direction to go in for the code. Can't give something that doesn't exist unless you just want a simple model that will give you no help for the sake of having code ;)

Comment: I answered with an attempt below but i think the models you have would help set the vernacular so i can see the relation you have :)

Comment: @NickBL check below if you see this.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is pull Quotes from the past x years(days, whatever) and the lines associated with them?

If so you can reference the line serializer in your quote serializer, and then when you hit the quote api, it will return quotes with the nested lines that relate to it:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

In your case i *think* (from what im reading) youd have something like this:

```py
class LineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Line
        fields = ('thing', 'date', 'etc')

class QuoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lines = LineSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Quote
        fields = ('quote_name', 'etc')
```

now when you hit your quotes view youll get the lines associated with it, so you only need to filter your quotes

Alternatively if you're determined to hit the lines endpoint and want the lines associated with a given quote you can do something like:
`lines = Line.objects.filter(Quote__QuoteID=givenQuoteId)`
note that "Quote" may vary depending on what you named the related model

Comment: Giving this a shot now. You nailed the models I have right on the nose. The reason I didnt include them is because they are gigantic. I suppose for the future I could just post something of a shortened version, but they are literally over 100 fields each so posting the full thing would have just made the question a nightmare to look at. Ill let you know shortly how the changes affect it. I have a good feeling after reading your answer

Comment: This works well except that it doesn't actually display the data at the quotes endpoint. It compiles, it runs, but the data isn't displayed as an object within the JSON which I believe means it probably isn't actually being serialized and couldn't be transferred to the front end?

Comment: ```class QuoteinfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    line = QuotelineSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
   
    class Meta:
        model = Quoteinfo
        fields = (
            'quoteid',
            'quotenumber',
            'quotecustomer',
            'quotecsr',

...

            'line' 

```
is what it looks like now\

Comment: Does the quote json object have an entry for 'lines' at all?